# Finding only topmost posts in Disqus using R/Selenium

Tags: r, selenium

First of all I apologise for the length of this post as I wanted to give enough detail of what I am trying to do.

I'm trying to perfect a scraping application I've written in R to get Disqus comments. So far I am able to obtain all the comments on a particular page, using the various RSelenium features. What I am trying to do now is to obtain a sort of tree structure from the posted comments, i.e. first get the topmost comments and then check if these comments have any children. A particular page from the website I'm using as an example has 34 comments in total but only 18 of those are the topmost ones. The rest are all children or children of children.

What I am doing is opening a page and creating a webdriver in Chrome, I use selectorgadget to find the right selectors to use as follows:

```
1. elem <- remDr$findElement(using = "id", value = "posts")
2. elem.posts <- elem$findChildElements(using = "id", value = "post-list")
3. elem.posts <- elem$findElements(using = 'css selector', value = '.post~ .post+ .post')
```

In the above code, line 1 finds the posts section and then if I use line 2 I get all the posts on the page after which I use the following line to find all the messages, so if there are 34 comments on the page I get them all.

`elem.msgs <- elem.posts[[1]]$findChildElements(using = 'css selector', '.post-message')`

Now I have realised that the "tree" structure of the comments could be important for my data project and am trying to get the topmost comments first then look into each top comment to find any available children. The example webpage is [here](http://disqus.com/embed/comments/?base=default&version=90aeb3a56d1f2d3db731af14996f11cf&f=malta-today&t_i=article_67726&t_u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.maltatoday.com.mt%2Fnews%2Fnational%2F67726%2Fair_malta_pilots_demands_30_basic_salary_increase&t_d=Air%20Malta%20pilots%E2%80%99%20demands%3A%2030%25%20basic%20salary%20increase%2C%20increased%20duty%20payments%2C%20double%20%E2%80%98denied%20leave%E2%80%99%20payment&t_t=Air%20Malta%20pilots%E2%80%99%20demands%3A%2030%25%20basic%20salary%20increase%2C%20increased%20duty%20payments%2C%20double%20%E2%80%98denied%20leave%E2%80%99%20payment&s_o=default). To get the comments I use lines 1 and 3 above and the result is a list of 16 and if i use `elem.posts[[1]]$getElementAttribute("id")` I obtain the post id which I can use to look for each top comment later on.

This list of 16 should be 18 and I cannot understand why the first two comments are not being captured in the list. This has happened in other pages where a number of topmost comments are not captured in the list.

My question is this: what can I try to use so that I can obtain all the topmost comments on a page without any comment drop-outs? Is there a better way to obtain the topmost comments without going through my inexperienced roundabout way?

Thanks for any help or direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive function to descend the posts. You only need RSelenium to get the page source:

```
library(xml2)
library(RSelenium)
library(jsonlite)
selServ <- startServer()
appURL <- "http://disqus.com/embed/comments/?base=default&version=90aeb3a56d1f2d3db731af14996f11cf&f=malta-today&t_i=article_67726&t_u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.maltatoday.com.mt%2Fnews%2Fnational%2F67726%2Fair_malta_pilots_demands_30_basic_salary_increase&t_d=Air%20Malta%20pilots%E2%80%99%20demands%3A%2030%25%20basic%20salary%20increase%2C%20increased%20duty%20payments%2C%20double%20%E2%80%98denied%20leave%E2%80%99%20payment&t_t=Air%20Malta%20pilots%E2%80%99%20demands%3A%2030%25%20basic%20salary%20increase%2C%20increased%20duty%20payments%2C%20double%20%E2%80%98denied%20leave%E2%80%99%20payment&s_o=default"
remDr <- remoteDriver()
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate(appURL)
pgSource <- remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]
remDr$close()
selServ$stop()
doc <- read_html(pgSource)
appNodes <- xml_find_all(doc, "//ul[@id='post-list']/li[@class='post']")
# write recursive function to get 
content_fun <- function(x){
  main <- xml_find_all(x, "./div[@data-role]/.//div[@class='post-body']")
  main <- list(
    poster = xml_text(xml_find_all(main, ".//span[@class = 'post-byline']")),
    posted = xml_text(xml_find_all(main, ".//span[@class = 'post-meta']")),
    date = xml_attr(xml_find_all(main, ".//a[@class = 'time-ago']"), "title"),
    message = xml_text(xml_find_all(main, ".//div[@data-role = 'message']"))
  )
  # check for children
  children <- xml_find_all(x, "./ul[@class='children']/li[@class='post']")
  if(length(children) > 0){
    main$children <- lapply(children, content_fun)
  }
  main
}

postData <- lapply(appNodes, content_fun)
```

For example here is the 3rd post

```
> prettify(toJSON(postData[[3]]))
{
    "poster": [
        "\nMary Attard\n\n"
    ],
    "posted": [
        "\n•\n\n\na month ago\n\n"
    ],
    "date": [
        "Thursday, July 21, 2016 6:12 AM"
    ],
    "message": [
        "\nI give up. Air Malta should be closed down.\n"
    ],
    "children": [
        {
            "poster": [
                "\nJoseph Lawrence\n\n Mary Attard\n"
            ],
            "posted": [
                "\n•\n\n\na month ago\n\n"
            ],
            "date": [
                "Thursday, July 21, 2016 7:43 AM"
            ],
            "message": [
                "\nAir Malta should have been privatized or sold out right a long time ago. It is costing the TAX PAYER millions, it has for a long, long time.\n"
            ]
        },
        {
            "poster": [
                "\nJ.Borg\n\n Mary Attard\n"
            ],
            "posted": [
                "\n•\n\n\na month ago\n\n"
            ],
            "date": [
                "Thursday, July 21, 2016 5:23 PM"
            ],
            "message": [
                "\nYes - at this stage we taxpayers will be better off without Air Malta. We closed Malta Dry Docks and we survived. We can close Air Malta and we'll survive even better. After all, we have many more airlines serving us.\n"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

You can clean up and scrape what content as needed.

Comment: I am experiencing some problems when executing the `appNodes <- xml_find_all(doc, "//ul[@id='post-list']/li[@class='post']")` line. My RStudio crashes with  R Session Aborted R encountered a fatal error. The session was terminated.

Would you have any idea why please?

Comment: Try running the code using commandline R. will rule out an RStudio issue.

Comment: **Maybe someone will find this useful.**
I did run the code from commandline R but had problems with read_html. Thanks for your input though :-)

The problem lies with the fact that my default R version was set to the 32-bit version. After setting the version to 64-bit, the problem went away.

Comment: I'm in a little jam again :-(
I would like to add the comment ID to the `postData` list resulting from the above. Using `appNodesId <- xml_attrs(appNodes, "//ul[@id='post-list']/li[@class='post']")` I am able to obtain a list of the topmost comment's ID's but modifying the same line and adding it to the content_fun function resulted in all the topmost id's being added to every element of the list. The modified line I used is `postId = xml_attrs(xml_find_all(main, "//ul[@id='post-list']/li[@class='post']"))`. Using `xml_find_first` returns only the first id but nothing for the children.Thanks