# CGlur's Data Tree in R: Recursive looping to find all children until leaf

Tags: r, dataframe, recursion, tree, treemap

I am trying to use ChristophGlur's Data tree to input a CSV that contains two columns & generate a tree. I found some posts already on this -  [How to recursively build a tree of unknown depth in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39124028/how-to-recursively-build-a-tree-of-unknown-depth-in-r) - but I get errors such as wrong arguments while subsetting environment or index out of bounds (I checked that I am using the right column name as well within the data frame). When I try the example in the posts, I get the same error. I am super new to R. So apologies if I have not figured out obvious features of the language.

When I follow CGlur's doc on CRAN, I can get my program to list the first child but nothing deeper than that. Here is a sample data. So as you can see below, parent 14650175 can have 4/5-digit children and 8/9 digit children. The 4/5 digits are always the leaf nodes. A 9-digit child indicates that there are children of these children. I need to list all the children of one parent until we reach the leaf. In the sample data below, if I queried for 14650175, I should get 14 children (17 children total but 3 9-digit children further broken into their leaves). Ideas?
Please ignore the numbering - that is not a data column, I just could not figure out how to insert a list in this post. My csv only has fc and ic which are the second and third columns below.

fc  ic

1. 14650160    1001
2. 14650160    1033
3. 14650160    1053
4. 14650160    2047
5. 14650160    14411
6. 14650165    11261
7. 14650165    11334
8. 14650165    11478
9. 14650165    11823
10. 14650165   14650160
11. 14650175   14650165
12. 14650175   21500100
13. 21500100   2047
14. 21500100   23563
15. 21500100   23568
16. 21500100   23573
17. 21500100   23578

Code that displays Depth=1 children

```
library(data.tree)
library(treemap)
test_Data <- read.csv("D:/tree_DATA.csv")
View(test_Data)
data(test_Data)
tree(test_Data)
test_Data$pathString <-  paste("ITree",test_Data$fc, test_Data$ic,sep ="/")
ing <- as.Node(test_Data)
```

Code that gives subsetting error

```
tree <- FromListExplicit(ing[1], nameName = "fc", childrenName = "ic")
```