# Can a data.tree be built using other trees as child nodes in R?

Tags: r, tree

I'm extracting comment data from a webpage's source and building trees using:

```
`tmpTree <- FromListExplicit(postData[[1]], nameName = "poster", childrenName = "child")`
```

where `postData` is a list of nodes extracted using `xml_find_all` and `postData[[1]]` is changed every time a new tree is created from the list. The functions to extract the nodes can be found in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38979593/finding-only-topmost-posts-in-disqus-using-r-selenium) I had posted in August and was thankfully answered by the creator of RSelenium himself, [jdharrison](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1690692/jdharrison).

What I would like to ask is whether I can create a sort of tree of trees for example:

```
newTree <- Node$new("Tree67770)
newTree$AddChild(tmpTree)
```

so that I end up with one tree made up of other threes that would then become nodes in the final tree and when I plot the large tree I can see all the names (the poster's).

The above did not work and the error `cannot coerce type 'environment' to vector of type 'character'` is understandable as each `tmpTree` is not character but a list. I thought of changing each tree into a data.frame and then add everything data.frame back to build one large tree but it seemed to me that it would be too long and cumbersome. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

**Edited to add dput examples:**
Example 1:

```
structure(list(postId = 2794984430, date = "Thursday, July 21, 2016 11:17 AM", 
poster = "MMM", disqusUname = "disqus_rVXuxnq9MP", message = "\rI am against abortion but I am in favour of contraceptives.  Is the MAP a (emergency) contraceptive or not?  Is the MAP abortive or not?  Unless there is clear unequivocal evidence about this, the circus will continue!\r", 
child = list(structure(list(postId = 2795948275, date = "Thursday, July 21, 2016 9:07 PM", 
    poster = "David Farrugia", disqusUname = "davidfarrugia", 
    message = "\rIt all depends when the soul has been installed into the egg. LOL\r"), .Names = c("postId", 
"date", "poster", "disqusUname", "message")))), .Names = c("postId", "date", "poster", "disqusUname", "message", "child"))
```

Example 2:

```
structure(list(postId = 2795142611, date = "Thursday, July 21, 2016 2:04 PM", 
poster = "David", disqusUname = "disqus_tTjwlqxma8", message = "\rthis reminds me of the Divorce debate.  the dinosaurs from church and the parliament seem to be against anything 'god' does not allow.  can they accept the fact that not all of us are into religious fairy tales?\r", 
child = list(structure(list(postId = 2796284665, date = "Friday, July 22, 2016 12:30 AM", 
    poster = "Nessy Testa", disqusUname = "NICOTI", message = "\rno they want to shove their \"morals\" down our throats.. then they go to repent their sins..\r"), .Names = c("postId", 
"date", "poster", "disqusUname", "message")))), .Names = c("postId", "date", "poster", "disqusUname", "message", "child"))
```

Each of the above examples produce a tree with a root and a child node and where chosen for their size as some others are 6 levels deep or more.

I used `tmpTree <- FromListExplicit(postData[[Example 1 or 2]], nameName = "poster", childrenName = "child")` to extract the tree which I then tried convert into a new node using:

```
newTree <- Node$new("root6770")
newNode <- Node$new(tmpTree)
newTree$AddChildNode(newNode)
```

with the result of the `Error in as.vector(x, "character") : 
  cannot coerce type 'environment' to vector of type 'character'` as soon as `newNode <- Node$new(tmpTree)` was executed.

I hope that with this example I explained myself better. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that's possible. Use `Node$AddChildNode` instead of `Node$new` to add a sub-tree to an existing node:

```
library(data.tree)
newTree <- Node$new("roottree")
tmpTree <- Node$new("subtree")
newTree$AddChildNode(tmpTree)
```

Comment: Thanks, will try this when I get home. BTW and just to make sure I'm understanding correctly, when you wrote `t2 <- Node$new("subtree")`, where you referring to the actual name of the node or a whole tree? Wouldn't adding `t2` as a child node just add it as a name without the other information? As I said, I'll try it later and will let you know the my outcome.

Comment: There is no distinction between Node and tree. A tree's entry point is the root node. And any other Node spans a sub-tree. `AddChild` is a shortcut for creating a `Node` and adding it using `AddChildNode`. And if you use `AddChildNode`, the node added is preserved (with all its attributes and descendants).

Comment: I have tried as suggested but am still faced with the `Error in as.vector(x, "character") : 
  cannot coerce type 'environment' to vector of type 'character'` when I use `ts <- Node$new(tmptree)`, so most probably I must be doing something wrong. When the above example was used the new child node did not have any other data as `subtree` is just a character string. I am editing my question so that I post a dput example of two of my (smallest) trees that I am trying to add as children under the same tree in the hope of explaining myself better. Thanks again.

Comment: Don't do `Node$new(tmptree)`. `Node$new()` creates a new `Node` object and expects the name of the node as argument. But your tmptree is already a `Node`, and you can add it as a sub-tree to any other node using `AddChildNode` as shown above.

Comment: Superb. I knew that I was doing something silly. Thanks a million.